# Scala Slick PositionedResult

Tags: scala, slick

I see the following example to retrieve firstOption.
Is there a way to retrieve all data ? I used list instead of firstOption and it results in only one value - I am using Slick 2.1

```
    import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult,PositionedResult}
    object ResultMap extends GetResult[Map[String,Any]] {
      def apply(pr: PositionedResult) = {
        val rs = pr.rs // <- jdbc result set
        val md = rs.getMetaData();
        val res = (1 to pr.numColumns).map{ i=> md.getColumnName(i) -> 
          rs.getObject(i) }.toMap
        pr.nextRow
        res
    }
    }
    val result = sql"select * from ...".as(ResultMap).firstOption
```